# Updating VHDL generic map values in execution

Tags: vhdl

Probably an easy one, but has been a while since I've dabbled in VHDL, but I'm trying to figure out how to properly change generic values of a sub-component after instantiation, when an event happens. Some pseudo code is below that jumps to the point:

```
U1: PARITY
  generic map (N   => 8)
  port map    (A   => DATA_BYTE,
               ODD => PARITY_BYTE);
....

process(Some_button_click)
begin
  // Change generic map value for N (integer) in PARITY to 10 //

end process;
```

I'm not in front of the code, but I've tried using 'shared variables' to no avail.... any help is greatly appreciated as this has been strangely hard to google.

Comment: Object declarations depending on a generic constant are fixed at elaboration, hardware (or it's description) isn't self modifying. The reason for changing `N` isn't clear without traceable declarations for `PARITY_BYTE`, `ODD`, potentially showing how `ODD` is used and limits potential solutions to speculation. `//` isn't a comment delimiter and challenges the specificity of your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Understood, this was more a generic question in the sense of plausibility rather than a specific problem, hence the rushed pseudo code. Wasn't looking for a code solution.

Answer (score 3):

I understand what you want to do, but as far as I  understand generics are mean to be used only to make components reusable and flexible. It does not make sense to change a constant value at run time. My suggestion is that if you need to change the value you better use a signal port